# Register Custom Helper Express and HBS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I'm a complete Node rookie so please bear with me.

I used the express generator module with -hbs flag to switch the default templating engine to handlebars.

I am now trying to register a custom helper to allow me to add page specific content to elements located in the layout template.

I can't find where I am supposed to register custom hbs helpers in express:
I've tried ".\node_modules\handlebars\dist\cjs\handlebars\compiler\helpers.js" with the following code (which I found here: http://www.apkapps.link/questions/2420017/handlebars-with-express-different-html-head-for-different-pages):

```
function section(name, options){
        if(!this._sections) this._sections = {};
        this._sections[name] = options.fn(this);
        return null;
    }

exports.section = section;
```

But when I try calling the helper from a template I get a "Missing helper: 'section'"

Can anybody point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the documentation of Handlebars, you have to register your helper as,

```
var hbs = require('hbs');

hbs.registerHelper('helper_name', function(...) { ... });
hbs.registerPartial('partial_name', 'partial value');
```

You don't need to modify ".\node_modules\handlebars\dist\cjs\handlebars\compiler\helpers.js

Comment: Thanks, i'd seen this in the documentation but as I'd also seen: app.set('view engine', 'hbs'); in my app.js i'd convinced myself it didn't apply. Thanks for the help!